# Mysql.h 0 results after query

Tags: c++

I made this:

```cpp
int querystate;
std::string pol;
std::string login;
std::cout << "login: ";
std::cin >> login;
pol = "select * from table where login = '" + login + "';";
querystate = mysql_query(conn, pol.c_str());
if (querystate != 0)
{
    std::cout << mysql_error(conn);
}
res = mysql_store_result(conn);

while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
{
    std::cout << row[0] << " " << row[1] << " " << row[2];
}
```

It is possible to make something like this?

```cpp
if (res == 0)
{
    cout<<"there is 0 results";
}
```

I want to output text when query returns 0 results, for example:

> there is no such login in the database.

Comment: You could try `if( mysql_fetch_row(res) == NULL )  cout << " There is no Results " ` . You can check the documentation for the same here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/5.7/en/mysql-fetch-row.html

Comment: @ThivinAnandh Okay but now when i typing correct login this while "while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)"  doesnt work

Comment: @ThivinAnandh where i must edit my code

Comment: Check the answer posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code is open to an SQL injection attack.  You need to escape the `login` string using [`mysql_real_escape_string_quote()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string-quote.html), eg:

```cpp
std::string escapeStr(MYSQL *mysql, const std::string &str, char quoteChar)
{
    std::string out((str.size()*2)+1, '\0');
    unsigned long len = mysql_real_escape_string_quote(mysql, out.data(), str.c_str(), str.size(), quoteChar);
    out.resize(len);
    return out;
}
```

```cpp
std::string pol = "select * from table where login = '" + escapeStr(conn, login, '\'') + "';";
```

Though, you really should be using a [prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-prepared-statement-interface.html) instead, let MySQL handle the escaping for you.

Second, the [`mysql_query()` documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-query.html) says:

> To determine whether a statement returns a result set, call `mysql_field_count()`. See [Section 5.4.23, “mysql_field_count()”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-field-count.html).

Where the `mysql_field_count()` documentation says:

> The normal use of this function is when `mysql_store_result()` returned NULL (and thus you have no result set pointer). In this case, you can call `mysql_field_count()` to determine whether `mysql_store_result()` should have produced a nonempty result. This enables the client program to take proper action without knowing whether the query was a `SELECT` (or `SELECT`-like) statement. The example shown here illustrates how this may be done.
>
> See [Section 3.6.8, “NULL mysql_store_result() Return After mysql_query() Success”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/null-mysql-store-result.html).

And that last document says:

> It is possible for `mysql_store_result()` to return NULL following a successful call to to the server using `mysql_real_query()` or `mysql_query()`. When this happens, it means one of the following conditions occurred:
>
> - There was a `malloc()` failure (for example, if the result set was too large).
> - The data could not be read (an error occurred on the connection).
> - The query returned no data (for example, it was an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE`).
>
> You can always check whether the statement should have produced a nonempty result by calling `mysql_field_count()`. If `mysql_field_count()` returns zero, the result is empty and the last query was a statement that does not return values (for example, an `INSERT` or a `DELETE`). If `mysql_field_count()` returns a nonzero value, the statement should have produced a nonempty result. See the description of the `mysql_field_count()` function for an example.

So, for example:

```cpp
std::string login;
std::cout << "login: ";
std::cin >> login;

std::string pol = "select * from table where login = '" + escapeStr(conn, login, '\'') + "';";
if (mysql_query(conn, pol.c_str()) != 0)
{
    std::cout << mysql_error(conn);
}
else if ((res = mysql_store_result(conn)) != NULL)
{
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << row[0] << " " << row[1] << " " << row[2];
    }
    mysql_free_result(res);
}
else if (mysql_field_count(conn) == 0)
{
    std::cout << "there are 0 results";
}
else
{
    std::cout << mysql_error(conn);
}
```

Alternatively, the documentation also says:

> An alternative is to replace the `mysql_field_count(&mysql)` call with `mysql_errno(&mysql)`. In this case, you are checking directly for an error from `mysql_store_result()` rather than inferring from the value of `mysql_field_count()` whether the statement was a `SELECT`.

```cpp
std::string login;
std::cout << "login: ";
std::cin >> login;

std::string pol = "select * from table where login = '" + escapeStr(conn, login, '\'') + "';";
if (mysql_query(conn, pol.c_str()) != 0)
{
    std::cout << mysql_error(conn);
}
else if ((res = mysql_store_result(conn)) != NULL)
{
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << row[0] << " " << row[1] << " " << row[2];
    }
    mysql_free_result(res);
}
else if (mysql_errno(conn) == 0)
{
    std::cout << "there are 0 results";
}
else
{
    std::cout << mysql_error(conn);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation available in this site  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/5.7/en/mysql-fetch-row.html

> When used after mysql_store_result(), mysql_fetch_row() returns NULL if there are no more rows to retrieve.

so use that to verify whether the data has rows or not. Since doing this once would have fetched a row already, you need to print them immediately before trying to get another row from the DB.

```
row = mysql_fetch_row(res)
if( row == NULL )    // This verifies whether data is NULL or not
    cout << " There is no Results "<<endl 

else { 
    do
    {
        std::cout << row[0] << " " << row[1] << " " << row[2];
    }
    while (row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
}
```

Comment: Its okay. Thank you for help